# How to program the computer to speak put loud in R

Tags: r, macos, voiceover

I have a script in R which returns *a* and I can print the result as

```
print(a)
```

Instead of *print()* I would like something like "speak()". So that the computer uses its "internal voice" and tells what the variable *a* is out loud.

Is this even possible in R?

(I use OSX)

(For example this "voice" can be heard in OSX when selecting a piece of text -> right-click -> speach -> begin speak.)

Comment: I don't have a mac but couldn't you just construct the string you want it to read and pass it to "say" via a system call?

Comment: Thanks it works great :D @Dason https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html

Comment: Glad to hear it! Why you don't you write up your solution and post it as an answer so future people with the same question have an easier time finding the answer.  Do it for the future answer seekers (keep in mind that this might be you - I've had times where I ended up finding the answer to my question here and it was from an answer I had written years ago).

Comment: I don't remember the exact conditions but I think low rep users have to wait a few hours before answering their own question.  Maybe try to come back tomorrow and post a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved!

As @Dason pointed out, it is possible to do a system call within R using [system()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html) and *say* as *command*.

The command in system() needs to be a complete string beginning with "say" and strings can be put together using [sprintf()](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Strings/Creating_strings_from_variables/).

Example:

```
a <- 2+5
b <- sprintf("say The result is %d", a)
system(b, intern = FALSE, ignore.stdout = FALSE, ignore.stderr =
    FALSE, wait = TRUE, input = NULL)
```