# String to Speech Conversion

Tags: r

Are there any R package that can make R to speak?
for example,

```
library(package)
text<-c("Hello, world!")
speak(text)
```

then, when I am running this script, the computer will say "hello world"

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://rdrr.io/cran/text2speech/man/tts.html) and [this](https://www.shirin-glander.de/2018/06/text_to_speech_r/).

Comment: Couple of related questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370664/does-r-studio-have-a-read-aloud-option-for-visually-impaired-data-scientists and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492300/how-to-program-the-computer-to-speak-put-loud-in-r

Comment: Hi couldnt find this package..```library(package)```

Comment: package ‘Rtts’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)